# Auto Refresh Javascript Url

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm new here and I'm still newbie in coding.

I have external javascript url. Example: domain.com/filename.js

Is that possible to make auto refresh (every 30 seconds) from external js url?

Please remember! The javacript file come from others site (cdn url), not in my own hosting. I already search in google, but i can't find the solution.

Maybe someone in here, can help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use any script loader. Then have a function to remove the script element or invalidate the cached script(using script loader) and make script loader to load the script again.

This one looks perfect for you: https://addyosmani.com/basket.js/.

```
function refreshScript() {
  basket.require({ url: 'http://domain.com/filename.js', unique: Date.now() }).then(function() {
    setTimeout(refreshScript, 5minsInMillis);
  });

}
refreshScript();
```

Comment: I already try but can't work for me. Can help me to see this fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/sez7xg0e/4/

Comment: @Ron: It appears basket depends on RSVP. Just added that dep and its working. Here is the updated fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/sez7xg0e/5/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done, you can keep the file wherever you want, it just needed to be called when it is required and it shall also contain the function for auto-refresh in every 30 seconds.

Comment: Dear Shahdeo, can you give to me the sample code that can auto-refresh external javascript url, please!

Comment: Just write this in your HTML page:

        <script src = "www.websiteurl.com/jsfile.js"></script>

enter your wesite URL and your file just as you include in your local js files